# split one column into two and combine in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this data in excel:

[image]

I'd like to have it read in pandas dataframe like the following:

[image]

Comment: Now your question doesn't say anything about what you have and what you want :-).

Comment: Had a problem with adding the image. Edited now.

Comment: Don't use images, text data are prefered.

Comment: Also, please make an attempt at solving the problem, and if you have trouble with that, then ask for help.

Comment: Quang, Thank you for your help. Your solution works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
df = pd.read_excel('file.xlsx')

df = pd.DataFrame(df['V1'].values.reshape(-1,2), columns=['V1','Value'])
```

Output:

```
  V1 Value
0  A     2
1  b     4
2  c     8
```